# How To Use ViewPager For Multiple Controls

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a screen which shows information about a contact.  When the user swipes left or right, it should go to the next contact.

I'm using ViewPager to do this, but am new to Android Development so can use some help in determining the best way to pull this off.  I followed the example here:  [Viewpager and listviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289425/viewpager-and-listviews) and it worked.  However I have 2 issues with it.

1) It only  works with a single ListView control.  I've got 3 TextViews and one ListView however (and will soon be adding an image), and all of them need to update.  How would I do this?  What's the best way?  Got an example?

2)The example from the link creates a single ListView for every page, I could have 200+ pages though, so that doesn't seem efficient.  Should I just create 2 and keep switching back and forth between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.  I created a new xml layout page with all the controls.  I gave all the controls id's.  On the activity that houses the viewpager, on initiate of the view pager I load the controls on the layout with the proper data based on the page index.  There's probably a better way, but this works for the short-term.