# Viewpager with listviews

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Has anybody had any luck with a view pager switching between fragments that contain listviews? In particular, the listviews I am working with inflate two separate layouts to get the desired effect. However, to my understanding this is causing the viewpager to disappear as well as the tabhost. I believe this to be so because it is working with other fragments that only inflate once.

Edit 1:

I was trying to see what would happen if I used one of the fragments that showed the tabhost and used the viewpager first. I would switch views and see the correct next one. However, shortly thereafter one of the fragments that does not show the tabhost or use the viewpager, for some odd reason, would load up.

Edit 2:
It's weird it is not even loading up on the right page. It should load up on 3 but instead it loads up on 2 and replaces the former screen that was actually supposed to be there.

Comment: similar question with accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8289425/3711562)

Comment: Some of the code in that example is deprecated

Comment: I've answered! Sorry for the delay...I had to type out a whole new project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding listviews to two fragments is very easy.

In short, you want to have a main activity that's the viewpager itself. Next, the viewpager is going to host two tabs (can be as many as you want, really) which will both contain separate layouts...each with a listview of its own.

## Code

The first thing we need to do is add some classes. I've made a GitHub Gist of 4 classes that I'd like you to implement into your project. You'll need to change the package name and R class to meet your project's needs.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/b3e9f1d0f8223ba2f8df

Second, we need to make our host activity. This is what will show the tabs and toolbar. See this next Gist as I don't want to spam up this answer with tons of code.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/8add2fc064397ab8efe4

You've probably gotten an error in the MainActivity.java file due to a missing ViewPagerAdapter class. That's up next!

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/fd70ee97c2e00d72f025

And finally, the tabs that'll show our listviews!

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/3e2a87706c98a69e7353

My apologies for taking so long in my response...I actually took the time to build all this code and error check it for you. I had an example of tabs once before but it was outdated...you weren't the only reason I made all this code. The full project can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/Andrew-Quebe/SlidingTabsExample

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Download the sample APK to see how everything looks: https://github.com/AMQTech/SlidingTabsExample/blob/master/APKs/Sample.apk?raw=true

Comment: Looks like a good example. I will try to figure out how to implement it. It's just that where you set an adapter to the listviews is where I would inflate another layout outside of the listviews layout. This layout would contain each listviews custom tile.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to apologize. I pointed you all in the wrong way. I did some research and as it turns out you cannot have the fragment container (frame layout) in the activity layout already. All I had to do was put the fragment container into a different layout and inflate it when the time came to switch to another fragment class and that fixed it. Thanks to everyone.