# Implementing viewpager in a list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

[How to implement an ExpandableList in a ViewPager in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991632/how-to-implement-an-expandablelist-in-a-viewpager-in-android/8129085#8129085)

My question is the exact opposite of the above question, I want to display a list view (preferably an expandable one) and when an item is clicked I want display a bunch of images (different ones for each item of course).

P.S: Please dont tell me to launch a different activity for each list item.

Answer (score 0):

This is some possible guidance not solution. (I am not exactly clear on what the problem is)

I would probably just create one activity. Each time you get a click on the listview it creates a intent with some stored flags. Then you start the activity with that intent. Unpackage the intent to find out what you want you activity to do.

```
private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, myclass.class);

        intent.putExtra(KEY, v.getId())
           intent.putExtra(KEY2, position)
           intent.putExtra(KEY3, id)
    startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

And then get the intents flags in the new activity onCreate()

```
  Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    resId = intent.getIntExtra(KEY, 0);
    ...
    super.setTitle(title);
```

Not sure if that what you were looking for hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I'm already doing, just wanted to know if there's a more efficient way. Anyway, another question, can you tell me how to create an onclick listener for an expandable activity (along with an onchildclicklistener). Thank you.

Comment: sorry I haven't built that before